# Feature selection with "overly important" features

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering, model-selection

I am very new to machine learning modeling, but I encountered a feature selection problem that I hope can get your insights on:

- For example, I have A,B,C,D as my independent variables and y as my
  dependent variable. The end user is more interested in C & D's impact
  on y since A and B are factors that the user don't have much power to
  change.
- But in the modeling, we see that A and B have very large
  feature importance in predicting y, while C and D have low prediction
  power.
- In this case, should I train the model only based on C&D or I
  should train the model based on ABCD？
- or is there any feature engineering I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a matter of clearly defining the target task:

- If the goal is to predict $y$ as accurately as possible and all 4 independent variables are available, then in general there's no reason not to use the 3 variables.
- If the goal is to predict $y$ using C and D only, or to calculate the impact of C and D on their own on $y$, then only C and D should be used, of course.

It might also be some kind of optimization problem where the goal is for instance to maximize $y$ using C and D, this would be a different problem.

Comment: I also suggest to do a variable study to improve you're knowledge about them. For example you can do some analysis like density plot, PCA or correlation. Maybe you discover new information about your data.